# Conditional test in recursive make call

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following source tree:

```
src
app1
├── Makefile
app2
├── 
app3 
├── Makefile
```

I want to call make in each app folder, and for that I have the following code:

```
APPS := $(wildcard $(APPS_DIR)/app*)

apps: $(APPS)
$(APPS):
ifneq ("$(wildcard $@/Makefile)","")
    @echo "Building $(patsubst $(APPS_DIR)/%, %, $@)..."
    @$(MAKE) -s -C $@
else
    @echo "No Makefile found for $(patsubst $(APPS_DIR)/%, %, $@)..."
endif
.PHONY: apps $(APPS)
```

Everything works without the conditional testing, which I need to avoid an error output from make in the case that an app folder doesn't has a Makefile file.

> make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop. make: ***
> [Makefile:203: /home/ubuntu/project/apps/app2] Error 2

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your question is not tagged for GNU make you're clearly using GNU make syntax so I'll reply as such.

You cannot use automatic variables like `$@` in conditional statements like `ifneq` because conditional statements are parsed *when the makefile is read in* but automatic variables are not set until much later, *when the rule is run*.

At the time of makefile parsing, variables like `$@` are not set so they resolve to the empty string.

You must use shell syntax to write the conditional statement, not make syntax:

```
$(APPS):
        if [ -n "$(wildcard $@/Makefile)" ]; then \
            echo "Building $(@F)..."; \
            $(MAKE) -s -C $@; \
        else \
            echo "No Makefile found for $(@F)..."; \
        fi
```

Or, if you're worried about portability to systems that don't have POSIX shells, you can use GNU make's if function:

```
$(APPS):
        $(if $(wildcard $@/Makefile), \
            echo "Building $(@F)..."; \
            $(MAKE) -s -C $@, \
            echo "No Makefile found for $(@F)...")
```

Comment: One more time, @madscientist to the gnumake rescue. :) It totally worked, and your explanation made me completely understand the issue. Thanks you!